# Google Maps API to show highway exit/mile market in xml/json output?

Tags: python, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

I've developed a script for work that measures the distance traveled in a route by a vehicle, what's the longest distance traveled, and whether the route was from point A to B, a loop, or the vehicle was simply in idle.

I'm using GoogleMaps API to determine all of this, and search through the XML data to determine the current location of the vehicle. There's a 'Vicinity' tag that tells what the current city is at that long/lat coordinate.

I don't see anything describing the current highway exit or mile marker, does anyone know how to get this information through Google?

I apologize if this was asked before. I found a similar post but it was from 7 years ago and stated that GoogleMaps currently did not offer that sort of service.

Comment: It does appear on the map when you're zoomed in enough.  Not sure if the API provides that information.  Which country?  Which highway?  Maybe I can find something, then I'll let you know

Comment: Thanks Emmanuel.

I've tried by using the api on lat/long that's right next to a highway exit to see if the XML output has any tags mentioning the exit, but none showed up.

This is in the US on a major interstate, but would need it to work for any highway/freeway in general within the US.

Comment: One thing I notice: the directions (if set in English) always say "merge onto ..." to enter a highway, and "Take ... exit" to exit one. example: "Take exit 209 for Cactus Rd".  It should be possible to read the exits from those instructions; then you can put those on the map.  So this only shows the exits that are taken, when a route is  plotted; it doesn't show other exits.  Would this help?

Comment: Emmanuel, that's a great idea. I didn't think of using the directions API which as you say does indeed mention exits. I will play around with it and see if I can integrate it into my script. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it works pretty well.
It makes double markers sometimes (like two merge markers a few yards apart).

There is some extra code that's probably not used, and some things commented out.
I copy/pasted most of this from another project I was working on.

```
<style>
body {
  width: 100%;
}
#right-panel, #map {
  height: 400px;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  overflow: auto;
}
hr {
  clear: both;
}
</style>

<input id="from" placeholder="from" value="Tulsa"/>
<input id="to" placeholder="to" value="Chicago"/>
<select onchange="routeType(this)">
  <option value="DRIVING">DRIVING</option>
  <option value="WALKING">WALKING</option>
  <option value="BICYCLING">BICYCLING</option>
  <option value="TRANSIT">TRANSIT</option>
</select>
<input value="plot" onclick="calculateRoute()" type="button"/>
<hr/>
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="right-panel"></div>
<hr/>
<input onclick="calculateRoute()" value="GO" type="button"/>
<div id="maplog"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry"></script>
<script>
var map;
var here = {};
var dest = {};
var directionsService;
var directionsDisplay;
var travelMode = 'DRIVING'; //'WALKING';
var sourcePosition;

function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {lat: 35, lng: -100},
        zoom: 5,
        mapTypeId: 'terrain'
    });
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: {lat: 50.8735506, lng: 4.3238525},
      map: map,
      title: 'Fermenthings winkel'
    });
    dest.marker = marker;
    directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
        draggable: true,
        suppressMarkers: true,
        panel: document.getElementById('right-panel'),
        map: map
    });
}
function trackLocation() {
    getLocation();

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);


function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
    //x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}
function showPosition(position) {
// x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +
// "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
    if(map) {

        sourcePosition = {lat: position.coords.latitude, lng: position.coords.longitude};
        //map.setCenter(sourcePosition);
        if(here.marker) {
            here.marker.setMap(null);
        }
        here.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: sourcePosition,
            draggable: true,
            icon: {url: 'thumbnails/here.png'},
            map: map
        });
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        bounds.extend(sourcePosition);
        bounds.extend(dest.marker.getPosition());
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
        google.maps.event.addListener(here.marker, 'position_changed', function() {
            sourcePosition =  {lat: this.getPosition().lat(), lng: this.getPosition().lng()};
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(here.marker, 'dragend', function() {
            sourcePosition =  {lat: this.getPosition().lat(), lng: this.getPosition().lng()};
            calculateRoute();
        });

        //return;
     }
     // route
    calculateRoute();
}

function createMarker(lat, lng, title) {
  return new google.maps.Marker({
      position: {lat: lat, lng: lng},
      map: map,
      title: title
    });
}
function displayRoute(origin, destination, service, display, waypoints, callback) {
    if(waypoints) {
        var options = {
            origin: origin,
            destination: destination,
            waypoints: waypoints,
            travelMode: travelMode //'DRIVING',
        };
    }
    else {
        var options = {
            origin: origin,
            destination: destination,
            travelMode: travelMode //'DRIVING',
        };
    }
    service.route(options, function(response, status) {
        if (status === 'OK') {
            //
            //createMarkers(response, callback);
            display.setDirections(response);
            if(callback) {
              callback(response);
            }
        } else {
            // alert('Could not display directions due to: ' + status);
        }
    });
}

function routeType(elm) {
    travelMode = elm.value;
    if(sourcePosition) {
        calculateRoute();
    }
}

function calculateRoute() {
    var from = document.getElementById('from').value;
    var to = document.getElementById('to').value;

    displayRoute(
        from, 
        to, 
        directionsService,
        directionsDisplay,
        null, //waypoints,
        function(response) {
          // loop steps
          var steps = response.routes[0].legs[0].steps;
          for(var i = 0; i<steps.length; i++) {
            var step = response.routes[0].legs[0].steps[i];
            // search for keywords in the instructions
            if( (step.instructions.indexOf('Take') > -1 || step.instructions.indexOf('take') > -1)  &&  step.instructions.indexOf('exit') > -1) {
              //here we enter a highway
              document.getElementById('maplog').innerHTML += 'exit: ' + step.start_location.lat() +','+ step.start_location.lng() +'<br/>';
              createMarker(step.start_location.lat(), step.start_location.lng(), 'exit');
            }
            if( (step.instructions.indexOf('Merge') > -1 || step.instructions.indexOf('merge') > -1)  &&  step.instructions.indexOf('onto') > -1) {
              //here we exit a highway
              document.getElementById('maplog').innerHTML += 'merge: ' + step.start_location.lat() +','+ step.start_location.lng() +'<br/>';
              createMarker(step.start_location.lat(), step.start_location.lng(), 'merge');
            }
          }
          //document.getElementById('maplog').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(response);
        }
    );
}
</script>
```